# Javascript convert timezone Z to +0000 with moment

Tags: javascript, momentjs

The backend API I am working with only understands timezone in +0000 format.

I currently I get a date in the current format:

"2017-12-20T16:39:31.000Z"

With moment.js how would I get it in the following string format?

2017-12-20T16:39:31+0000

So far I have done:

```
var date = new Date();
this.lastCheckedDate = moment(date).toISOString();
```

Comment: Any system that understands `Z` or `+0000` ought to be able to treat them interchangeably - are you sure you need to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`.format()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) method to format the date in your own way:

```
moment("2017-12-20T16:39:31.000Z").format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZZ');
```

If the date is in another timezone, I recommend using [`.utc()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc/) first to convert the timezone to UTC, and then format the date:

```
moment("2017-12-20T16:39:31.000+0530").utc().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZZ');
```

Comment: Please note that you don't need moment-timezone to convert moment object to UTC, you can use [`utc()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc/). Moment.js supports natively local time and UTC, see more [here](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/local-utc-zone/).

Comment: @VincenzoC -- thanks for pointing this out. I've updated the code.